# Entity type ‘Business_attrib2object’ has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I set composite primary key using fluent API, it is still an error, when I'm trying to create ClassesController (MVC Controller with Views Using Entity Framework).

Declaring Classes class:

```
public partial class Classes
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Classes()
    {
        this.Business_attrib2object = new HashSet<Business_attrib2object>();
        this.Objects = new HashSet<Objects>();
    }
    [Key]
    public System.Guid IdClass { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Business_attrib2object> Business_attrib2object { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Objects> Objects { get; set; }
}
```

Declaring Business_attrib2object class:

```
 public partial class Business_attrib2object
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid IdClass { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public System.Guid IdAttribute { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.Guid> IdAuthor { get; set; }

    public virtual Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
    public virtual Classes Classes { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
public class Business_attrib2objectContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Business_attrib2object> Business_attrib2object { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Business_attrib2object>().HasKey(ba => new { ba.IdClass, ba.IdAttribute });      
    }

    public Business_attrib2objectContext(DbContextOptions<Business_attrib2objectContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

Creating controller:
[Creating controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC2Ux.png)
Error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V2Ob.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure what the confusion is. The error is explicit. You've got data attributes specifying a composite primary key, and you can't do that. You've already got the necessary fluent config in your context, so just remove the two `[Key]` data attributes on your `Business_attrib2object` class.

Answer (score 21):

If you used this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Business_attrib2object>().HasKey(ba => new { ba.IdClass, ba.IdAttribute });      
}
```

You don't need this:

```
public partial class Business_attrib2object
{
    [Key]
    public System.Guid IdClass { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public System.Guid IdAttribute { get; set; }

    ...
```

Just remove the `[Key]` attributes that it should work:

```
public partial class Business_attrib2object
{
    public System.Guid IdClass { get; set; }
    public System.Guid IdAttribute { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.Guid> IdAuthor { get; set; }

    public virtual Attributes Attributes { get; set; }
    public virtual Classes Classes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do not have the first method. but When I used the first method and remove the [key] then it works!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is incomplete (at least for EF6):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Business_attrib2object>().HasKey(ba => new { 
    ba.IdClass, ba.IdAttribute });      
}
```

Use this instead:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Business_attrib2object>().HasKey(ba => new { 
    ba.IdClass, ba.IdAttribute });      
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).